# Sencha touch 2. Making MVC grid

Tags: extjs, grid, touch

i have a example of sencha touch 2 Grid. But when i try to make the same project, but like mvc, it gives me a some problems. The main problem with grid library. Some files cant find them. Could you halp me with mvc grid?

My code:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths   : {
        'Ext.ux.touch.grid': './Ext.ux.touch.grid'
    }
});

Ext.require([
    'Ext.ux.touch.grid.List',
    'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Feature',
    'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Sorter'
]);

Ext.define('TestModel',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

     config: {
          fields : [
              'company',
              'price',
              'change',
              'pct',
              'updated'
            ]
        }
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model   : 'TestModel',
        data    : [
            { company : '3m Co',                               price : 71.72, change : 0.02,  pct : 0.03,  updated : '9/1/2010' },
            { company : 'Alcoa Inc',                           price : 29.01, change : 0.42,  pct : 1.47,  updated : '9/1/2010' },
            { company : 'Altria Group Inc',                    price : 83.81, change : 0.28,  pct : 0.34,  updated : '9/1/2010' },
            { company : 'American Express Company',            price : 52.55, change : 0.01,  pct : 0.02,  updated : '9/1/2010' },
            { company : 'American International Group, Inc.',  price : 64.13, change : 0.31,  pct : 0.49,  updated : '9/1/2010' },
            { company : 'AT&#38;T Inc.',                       price : 31.61, change : -0.48, pct : -1.54, updated : '9/1/2010' },
            { company : 'Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.',               price : 45.45, change : 0.73,  pct : 1.63,  updated : '9/1/2010' }
        ]
    });

Ext.setup({
  onReady: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.ux.touch.grid.List', {
        fullscreen : true,
        store      : store,

        features   : [
            {
                ftype    : 'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Sorter',
                launchFn : 'initialize'
            }
        ],
        columns   : [
            {
                header    : 'Company',
                dataIndex : 'company',
                style     : 'padding-left: 1em;',
                width     : '40%',
                filter    : { type : 'string' }
            },
            {
                header    : 'Price',
                dataIndex : 'price',
                style     : 'text-align: center;',
                width     : '15%',
                filter    : { type : 'numeric' }
            },
            {
                header    : 'Change',
                dataIndex : 'change',
                cls       : 'centered-cell redgreen-cell',
                width     : '15%',
            },
            {
                header    : '% Change',
                dataIndex : 'pct',
                cls       : 'centered-cell redgreen-cell',
                width     : '15%',
            },
            {
                header    : 'Last Updated',
                dataIndex : 'updated',
                hidden    : true,
                style     : 'text-align: right; padding-right: 1em;',
                sortable  : false,
                width     : '15%'
            }
        ]
    });
}       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this in your example:

```
 paths : {
   'Ext.ux.touch.grid': './Ext.ux.touch.grid'
 }
```

If I changed the above code to the below code it started working:

```
 paths : {
   'Ext.ux.touch.grid': 'js/Ext.ux.touch.grid'
 }
```